# My program won't stop when I enter "done"

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I asked a question earlier and since then i've edited my code a bit but now my code won't stop when i reads in done it does not stop.

```
public class Done {

    public static void main(String[] args){

       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
       ArrayList<String> sal = new ArrayList<String>();
       int count = 0;
       while (true){
             sal.add(kb.next());
             if (sal.equals("done"))
                 break;
             count++;
      }
      display(sal);
      displayb(sal);
    }

    public static void display(ArrayList<String> sal){

       for (int i=0; i<sal.size(); i++)
            System.out.print(sal.get(i)+ " ");
       System.out.println();
     }

    public static void displayb(ArrayList<String> sal){

       for (int z = sal.size(); z >= 1; z--)
            System.out.print(sal.get(z-1) + " ");
       System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

My code won't stop when I enter the phrase "done." Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You should never use break to end a loop... you should instead invert your desired statement and put it in the while loop.

Comment: @Dom sorry, I don't know where you heard this, but it's baloney.  You can't always put the `!` of the desired statement in the `while` condition.  You can't do it here because you have to do the input first.  And the only way you could do it is to write the input call `kb.next()` twice, which is duplicated code, which is something that should be avoided more than `break`.  There are other ways to rewrite the code to avoid `break` but they will make it less readable.

Answer (score 6):

You're checking if the `ArrayList` `sal` is equal to the string `"done"` -- this will never be true. Perhaps you want to check if the latest input is equal to that string:

```
while (true)
{
    String input = kb.next();

    if (input.equals("done"))
        break;

    sal.add(input);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: @user2920249 Try the edited code (i.e. just check for done *before* adding to the list).

Comment: @nhgrif: What's better about that?

Comment: @FredLarson It won't throw an exception if/when `input` is null.  In this specific case, it may never be null, but it's just good to be in the habit of writing it this way.

Comment: @nhgrif I generally don't use yoda conditions with strings -- if my string is null I want to know about it and fail early.

Answer (score 1):

`kb.next()` is the string you want to compare.  You'll need to save that in a variable:

```
String inputString = kb.next();
if (inputString.equals("done"))
    break;
sal.add(inputString);
```

That will also solve the problem of not adding `"done"` to the array.